# how to prevent two divs from wrapping and also no horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I have some divs set up as follows
 http://jsfiddle.net/hwffdodx/10/

```
<div>
<div style="display:inline"> [Button A] </div>
<div style="display:inline">Some looooooooooooooooooooooooong text hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
</div>
```

basically,I would like two divs on the same line,first div I will use to show an icon, second div I would like it to wrap within itself when window is resized.

I have tried to use "white-space:nowrap", but it will show a scrollbar on the bottom when window resized, which is not what I want.

I have also tried to set a "width" to the second div, but I hope I can find a better solution since there are a bounch of block of this style in my html, which all have different parent left padding,so it is difficult to preset a single width.

Now I use "display:inline" to make things display on the same line. But now indentation doesn't respect the first div that contains button any more.

Any idea of solving this?

Thanks!

**Update:**

one solution I found("overflow:hidden" works like magic...):

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <div style="float:left"> [Button A] </div>
    <div style="overflow:hidden">Some looooooooooooooooooooooooong text eeeeeeereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
</div>
```

Now, two divs always on the same line and no scrollbar will show up when resize. And, indentation works perfectly(comparing to just use "inline for all divs)

Comment: overflow: hidden on the parent? your question is not very clear

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want... An image would have been great to better understand what you're asking. Maybe one of these will help you: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqaakrhz/). Also if you're going to set div's to inline or inline-block then consider using a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`.

Comment: @onetrickpony, basically I would like two divs always on the same line ( nowrap) and no horizontal scroll bar also(I mean, text will just wrap within the second div when window shrinks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is what you want to achieve but it may help :

```css
.icon {
    display: inline;
    max-width: 20%;
}
.content {
    float: right;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="icon">[Button A]</div>
    <div class="content">Some looooooooooooooooooooooooong text hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
</div>
```

Ps : Run code snippet in <kbd>full page</kbd> mode or see [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwffdodx/11/)

Comment: Thanks Kaiido!Is there a way to work without setting width? So I have this "button-text" in a lot of places of my html and they all have different left-paddings.